# Dependent Parameter not Populating in Visual Studio(SSRS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

My Independent parameter is WellID the Dependent parameter is JobID. 
Both JobID and WellID are columns in the Primary Key of the table DailyReports.

Independent Parameter Query:

```
Select Distinct WellID from DailyReports
```

Dependent Parameter Query:

```
Select Distinct JobID From DailyReports
Where (JobID IN (@WELLID))
```

The Independent Parameter pulls up the WellID's but the Dependent Parameter is blank. I have tried setting both to Always refresh. I followed several guides on parameters but cannot get mine to work.

Comment: You cannot pass in a list of ids for `IN` using a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try using filter tab in dataset properties instead of (JobID IN (@WELLID)) like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out after three days of trying. I am a bit slow. Ultimately this is what worked for the dependent parameter:

Select Distinct JobID,WellID From DailyReports
Where (WellID IN(@WellID))

All I needed was to replace JobID with WellID.